# How to get an "inner type" of a specific "instance" of a generic in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Couldn't find better words to explain it beyond what's in the title, so I'm gonna let the code do the talking:

```
let var1 = someExternalLibraryMethod(); // assume var1 is implicitly Promise<string>

let var2: typeof var1; // this works, and this way I can "bind" the types of both vars without hardcoding them to the same type (i.e. instead of let var2: Promise<string>;)

let var3: ???????; //I want to "bind" this type to var1's "inner" type without hardcoding it (i.e. instead of let var3: string;)
```

My choice of `Promise<string>` was arbitrary. I'm looking for a way of doing this that would work with other "instances" of generic types, e.g. `rxjs.Observable<number>` and `mongoose.Schema<{_id: number}>`.

It should also work without having to hard code the "outer" type. That is, the word 'Promise' shouldn't appear anywhere. If TypeScript does actually support this, I would guess the syntax would go something like

```
let var3: InnerTypes<typeof var1>[0]; // This is a guess and does not actually work
```

Typescript version: 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional types. Here's the general idea:

```
type Container = ReturnType<typeof someExternalLibraryMethod>; // Promise<string>
type Inner = Container extends Promise<infer I> ? I : never;
```

The key point is the fact that the inner type can be inferred inside `extends` query.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3mpBbEAogB4YgwpQQAyAlgEYywCeAsiBgBZLABc8AFAEp4AXgB88AAow8NNCAA8mGDRQBzMQG4AUNoxMADggDCqDFFVlR8AErsAruQAqhxfqNIAZtjyESZCmp6RhhWdi5gLXgAemipGVw5RWVVDT1XeABJFBQrEXhTFHNLGHgQfxRgNHjZeQVVTytMiQB+LPg+XIA3Mh1tZHQsUkw+bNzS-IBySZ1YxFRMeCQkAzRRnLz4AAZNeABaeBcjeEmtyfg5eBQkLCg0NBo1CjoIBAwkeHcESZT1SaA)

Comment: While this already quite helpful, I think I wasn't clear enough. I'm looking for a way of doing it that doesn't include hard coding outer type (i.e. Promise) either. I've edited the question to further specify it.