# How to get Type from Response<Type> function argument?

Tags: typescript

I am using [`got` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) to make API requests like this:

```
const res1 = await got.get<MyResBody1>(url1, opts); // res1 => Response<MyResBody1>
const res2 = await got.get<MyResBody2>(url2, opts); // res2 => Response<MyResBody2>
```

Then I have a function that extracts response body (slightly more complex than this):

```
const parseBody = (res: Response) => JSON.parse(res.body)
```

However, I am struggling to type it properly. What I want is for `parseBody` to infer `MyResBody1` and `MyResBody2` from `WhateverThisIs` in `Response<WhateverThisIs>` that it receives as the only argument:

```
const body1 = parseBody(res1); // body1 => MyResBody1
const body2 = parseBody(res2); // body2 => MyResBody2
```

Something like this:

```
const parseBody = (res: Response<WhateverThisIs>): WhateverThisIs => JSON.parse(res.body)
```

Is this possible?

**Edit 1**: I am trying to **infer** `WhateverThisIs` in `Response<WhateverThisIs>` without explicitly declaring `WhateverThisIs` with generics.

**Edit 2**: my failed attempt with @Cerberus suggestion:

```
type GetType<T> = T extends Response<infer I> ? I : never;

const parseBody = (res: Response): GetType<typeof res> => JSON.parse(res.body)

const body1 = parseBody(res1); // body1 => unknown (should be MyResBody1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Generics in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027362/what-is-generics-in-typescript)

Comment: A possible answer to your specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57156161/how-to-get-an-inner-type-of-a-specific-instance-of-a-generic-in-typescript/57157598#57157598

Comment: @Blackhole Thanks, I am familiar with generics, but I was wondering about *type inference* (likely using the right combination of `extends` and `infer`) without explicit declaration.

Comment: @Cerberus I made an edit with another attempt, but I'm still missing something.

Comment: @Alex - `parseBody` must be a generic function. `<T extends Response>(res: T): GetType<T> => `

Comment: Why don't you want to use generics? It is the obvious and one-line solution, in your case.

Comment: @Blackhole Because I needed to get not the type itself, but its "inner type" (between the square brackets, if that makes sense).

Comment: I understand that, and it's easy with generics: `const parseBody = <T,>(res: Response<T>): T => JSON.parse(res.body)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution thanks to @Cerberus and @Tobias S.:

```
type MyResBody1 = { a: string };
type MyResBody2 = { b: string };

type GetType<T> = T extends Response<infer I> ? I : never;

const parseBody = <T extends Response>(res: T): GetType<T> =>
  JSON.parse(res.body as string);

const main = async () => {
  const res1 = await got.get<MyResBody1>("url1", {});
  const res2 = await got.get<MyResBody2>("url2", {});

  const body1 = parseBody(res1); // => MyResBody1
  const body2 = parseBody(res2); // => MyResBody2
};
```